# How to increase ShortCache high value in Java

Tags: java, caching, jvm, command-line-interface, short

The following options set the high value for `IntegerCache` in Java:

```
-XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=42000 -Djava.lang.Integer.IntegerCache.high=21000
```

But the following doesn't seem to work

```
-Djava.lang.Short.ShortCache.high=21000
```

I checked it in the memory profiler, and multiple `Short` instances are allocated for the same numeric value.

So how to set the high value for `ShortCache` in Java, if it's possible?

Comment: checked the source code, you cannot change it (Java 8, Java 19, [github](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/2f7dc5c4cde32978c46d092d593c5c76df1edc18/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Short.java#L274))  :-|

Comment: Use Java agent to redefine `Short.valueOf`

Comment: Do you really need `Short` instances? If you just use `Integer` instances consistently, you can skip creating 21000 `Short` instances. The only place where you can not use an `Integer` instead of `Short`, is when invoking a `Method` with `short` parameter, but this can easily circumvented by using a `MethodHandle` instead.